# Why is nil in a decimal field returning as zero?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a table with a decimal attribute. When I initialize a record, the value is shown as `nil`, but when I run `record.decimal_attribute` it comes back as `0.0`. There are no constraints/defaults in the migration or in the model. I'm using Postgres.

```
w = SomeModel.create(name: 'widget')
# => <SomeModel id: 1, name: 'widget', price: nil>

w.price
# => 0.0

w.price.nil?
# => false
```

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: Are you sure there is no call to `to_f` in `decimal_attribute`? e.g. `nil.to_f #=> 0.0`

Comment: You're right! I have a getter that does a float conversion. I'd completely forgotten about it. If you'll post this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.